# Ошибка при попытке парсить сообщения через Telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telethon

В общем есть бот на питоне который отправляет мне сообщение если в группах, которые изначально я считываю из файла, присутствуют слова, которые также изначально я считываю из файла, тут ошибок нет, но также бот при запуске должен мне отправлять предыдущие сообщения в которых эти слова присутствуют, вот здесь какая то ошибка. Надеюсь все понятно, вот код

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from env import *
import re

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=token)

with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as file:
    keywords = [line.strip() for line in file]

with open('groups.txt', 'r') as file:
    groups = [int(line.strip()) for line in file]


async def get_previous_messages(chat_ids, limit=10):
    for chat_id in chat_ids:
        try:
            chat_entity = await client.get_entity(chat_id)
            group_name = chat_entity.title
            messages = (await client(GetHistoryRequest(
                peer=chat_id,
                limit=limit,
                offset_date=None,
                offset_id=0,
                max_id=0,
                min_id=0,
                add_offset=0,
                hash=0
            ))).messages
            for message in messages:
                for keyword in keywords:
                    if re.search(rf'\b{re.escape(keyword)}\b', message.text, re.IGNORECASE):
                        await client.send_message(
                            admin_id,
                            f'Найдено сообщение в группе {group_name} ({chat_id}):\n\n{message.text}'
                    )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Произошла ошибка при получении сообщений для группы {chat_id}: {e}")


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=groups))
async def search_messages(event):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if re.search(rf'\b{re.escape(keyword)}\b', event.message.text, re.IGNORECASE):
            chat_id = event.chat_id
            chat_entity = await client.get_entity(chat_id)
            group_name = chat_entity.title

            await client.send_message(
                admin_id,
                f'Найдено сообщение в группе {group_name} ({chat_id}):\n\n{event.message.text}'
            )


async def main():
    await get_previous_messages(groups)
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

ошибка в этой строчке кода

```
messages = (await client(GetHistoryRequest(
            peer=chat_id,
            limit=limit,
            offset_date=None,
            offset_id=0,
            max_id=0,
            min_id=0,
            add_offset=0,
            hash=0
        ))).messages
```

`Exception` такой:
`Произошла ошибка при получении сообщений для группы -1002008511201: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetHistoryRequest)`

Без `Exception` в консоли такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке указано, что данный метод не может использоваться с bot API, то есть необходимо авторизироваться как пользователь.

Через бота можете получить данные конкретного сообщения через ид используя метод
`GetMessageRequest(channel="логин канала через @", id=[i])`
где `i` - целое число

Как будете получать ид сообщений, уже вам решать, но через бота, это единственное рабочее решение, которое нашел. [Документация.](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/get_messages.html)